# Japanese Sci-Fi Where Man's Chest Splits Open And Glows

Tags: story-identification, movie, b-movies

Caught part of a '60-ish Japanese sci-fi flick on Turner Classic Movies where the hero and his girl are either in a crater or on another planet with a crashed space ship in the background.

Dunno what triggers it, but suddenly his chest starts to split open and there's a lava-like radiating glow shining out of the split.

Anyone have any idea what this movie's title might be?

Answer (score 4):

There is *Goke, Body Snatcher from Hell* (1968), which involves people crashed in a crater, with their ruined airplane. At about 1:08 in the video, one character's face (not chest) splits open and glowing ooze comes out.

Comment: Thanks, Buzz, but I gotta tell ya, I don't think this is it.

I saw Goke a couple of years ago and it seemed close, but the film I'm thinking of has the scene I described set at night.  That I recall, the guy pulls his shirt open to reveal the glowing split chest.

And then again . . . maybe my meds were wearing off. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, Buzz, but I gotta tell ya, I don't think this is it.  I saw Goke a couple of years ago, and it seemed pretty close.  The in the scene I described above, the setting was at night, and that I recall, the guy pulled his shirt open to reveal the orange-glowing split in his chest.